# Implementing bitmask verification in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, bitmask

I have a table `Watchlist` that contains a number of players and a flag to idenfity their offenses. I want to implement the flag as a `bitmask`. However, to catch wrong input at an early stage, I would like to check the bitmask against the table `Watchlist_Flags` before the value is set.

Basically, I'm looking for an SQL query to verify that the about-to-be set bitmask flag is indeed composed of, and ONLY of, flag IDs present in the table `Watchlist_Flags`

---

Is it possible to implement this on an SQL level or do I need to deal with this in the final software?

Comment: This is for SQL Server, but I remember at one stage converting it to MS Access, so it may be of interest: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2007/05/29/test.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to populate a combo box with the values of Watchlist_Flags.  Have a user select the value from that combo box, and when adding/updating a record, use the value selected in the SQL statement which adds/updates the data in Watchlist.

Comment: Because the flags are part of a bitmask, populating a ComboBox with values would be much more work than intended since the ComboBox would have to contain all possible combinations of all flags.

Comment: I didn't realize there would be several combinations of flags that could be selected.  My apologies for offering an inadequate solution.  Remou may have a very workable solution, then.